# How to display text under background image?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm making a site where I have three `<li>` all floated to the left and they each have a background of a certain image. I have text in each of the `<li>` and I want to move that text so that it is displayed under the background instead of on it. What would the css for this sort of layout be?

Below I have an example of what I would like the layout to be. Thanks for the help.

======   ======   ====== 
  |            |    |            |    |           | 
  |            |    |            |    |           | 
  ======   ======   ====== 
     text            text             text

I have no ASCII art skills but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: sorry but i'm a wolly and don't know what your asking for show me your html here on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net so maybe i can get a better idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the text in a span with a `margin-top` equal to the height of the background image.  The span will need to be `display: block` for this to work.  Or, better yet, just set `padding-top` equal to the height of the background image, with `background-image-repeat: no-repeat`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/77NdE/ for a working example.

Comment: You can do this without the extra markup by applying padding to the `li`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're setting the height to a fixed size.  If that is the case, you can set the `padding-top` to be the same as the height of the image, and as long as `background-repeat` is `no-repeat`, you should see your comment below.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qTB8E/

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a fixed height for your li elements. The height would be 'the height of the background image in use' + 'the height required by the text that goes under it'. Then apply padding on top for the li element which is equal to the height of the background image.

Suppose the background image is 14px in height and lets assume that the text under it is 12px. Then,

```
li
{
height: 26px; /* 14 + 12 */
background-image: url(path/to/image);
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* you can even repeat x if required */
padding-top: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the div's height to accommodate both text and background. Set background to no-repeat and give padding-top for the text.

Comment: What div? It is `li` element. It doesn't work with li unless you set `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with pseudo classes

```
<ul>
<li id="background"></li>
<li>Text</li>
<li id="background"></li>
<li>Text</li>
<li id="background"></li>
<li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {}
ul li:nth-child(even) {padding-top:20px}
```

So every second (every even number) li element will have a padding from the top with 20px (Change it to your li-background height or higher) Change "even" to "odd" to get every odd number aligned. Hope u can figur it out what i mean :)

Comment: There are easier ways to accomplish this without adding extra `li` elements and making a mess of the html.

Comment: But the task is, to solve it with the all the li elements. He never asked for better html. So why the downvote?

Comment: It's an overly complicated solution to a simple problem.

Comment: As I said, he asked for all the li elemts, who knows what he wanne do, maybe he needs all the `li`. For his question its the right answer.